# Find last non-zero element in column for each group, fill different column

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, match

I am trying to create a for loop that does the following:

```
for (i in 2:length(Exampledata$Levels)) { 
  if(is.na(Exampledata$Levels[i]) == "TRUE"    {   
    find the last instance where 
is.na(Exampledata$Levels) == "FALSE" 
  for that same ID, and input 
the day from that row into last_entry[i]
  }
}
```

Example data:

```
ID<-c("QYZ","MMM","QYZ","bb2","gm6","gm6","YOU","LLL","LLL","LLL")
day<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
values<-c(1,2,4,5,5,6,8,9,6,4)
Levels<-c("A","","A","C",'D','D',"C","y","","")
last_entry<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
```

What data currently looks like:

```
    ID values Levels day last_entry
1  QYZ      1      A   1          0
2  MMM      2          2          0
3  QYZ      4      A   3          0
4  bb2      5      C   4          0
5  gm6      5      D   5          0
6  gm6      6      D   6          0
7  YOU      8      C   7          0
8  LLL      9      y   8          0
9  LLL      6          9          0
10 LLL      4         10          0
```

What I want it to look like:

```
    ID values Levels day last_entry
1  QYZ      1      A   1          0
2  MMM      2          2          0
3  QYZ      4      A   3          0
4  bb2      5      C   4          0
5  gm6      5      D   5          0
6  gm6      6      D   6          0
7  YOU      8      C   7          0
8  LLL      9      y   8          0
9  LLL      6          9          8
10 LLL      4         10          8
```

I have seen a lot of code that looks for last non-zero elements or last is.na=FALSE, but none that can do it by ID, and extract a value from that row. I also need to ignore cases where there is no entry for that ID.

Essentially I want to know the last day that a level was entered for that ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using data.table:

```
library('data.table')
dt <- data.table(ID = c("QYZ","MMM","QYZ","bb2","gm6","gm6","YOU","LLL","LLL","LLL"), 
                 Day = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10),
                 values = c(1, 2, 4, 5, 5, 6, 8, 9, 6, 4), 
                 Levels = c("A", NA, "A", "C", "D", "D", "C", "y", NA, NA),
                 last_entry = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))

func <- function(days, levels){
  if(!any(is.na(levels)) | all(is.na(levels))) return(0)
  return(last(days[which(!is.na(levels))]))
}

dt[, last_entry := ifelse(!is.na(Levels), 0, func(Day, Levels)), by = ID]
```

But if you're set on using a for loop:

```
ID <- c("QYZ","MMM","QYZ","bb2","gm6","gm6","YOU","LLL","LLL","LLL")
Day <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
Levels <- c("A", NA, "A", "C", "D", "D", "C", "y", NA, NA)
last_entry <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)


i.na <- which(is.na(Levels))
for(id in unique(ID)){
  i.id <- which(ID == id)
  if(all(is.na(Levels[i.id])) | !any(is.na(Levels[i.id]))) next
  day <- last(Day[i.id[!(i.id %in% i.na)]])
  last_entry[i.na[i.na %in% i.id]] <- day
}
```

Comment: Any suggestions for running the first option (most intuitive to me) on a dataset where "day" is actually a date in YYYY-MM-DD format? Currently it just outputs TRUE/FALSE

Comment: Make both the Day column and the last_entry column characters.

`dt[, Day := seq(from = as.Date('2019-01-01'), to = as.Date('2019-01-10'), by ='days')]`  

`dt[, Day := as.character(Day)]`  

`dt[, last_entry := as.character(last_entry))]`  

`dt[, last_entry := ifelse(!is.na(Levels), 0, func(Day, Levels)), by = ID]`

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way using `tidyr::fill`. We replace the `last_entry` columns with `NA` where the Levels are empty, then use `fill` to replace those `NA`'s with latest non-NA values and turn `last_entry` value of all non-empty `Levels` to 0.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(last_entry = ifelse(Levels  != "",  day, NA)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  tidyr::fill(last_entry) %>%
  mutate(last_entry = replace(last_entry, Levels != "" | n() == 1, 0))


#   ID      day values Levels last_entry
#   <fct> <dbl>  <dbl> <fct>       <dbl>
# 1 QYZ       1      1 A               0
# 2 MMM       2      2 ""              0
# 3 QYZ       3      4 A               0
# 4 bb2       4      5 C               0
# 5 gm6       5      5 D               0
# 6 gm6       6      6 D               0
# 7 YOU       7      8 C               0
# 8 LLL       8      9 y               0
# 9 LLL       9      6 ""              8
#10 LLL      10      4 ""              8
```

---

We can also do

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID)  %>%
  mutate(last_entry =  purrr::map_dbl(row_number(), ~if (Levels[.x] == "" & n() > 1) 
                       day[max(which(Levels[1:.x] != ""))] else 0))
```

**data**

```
ID<-c("QYZ","MMM","QYZ","bb2","gm6","gm6","YOU","LLL","LLL","LLL")
day<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
values<-c(1,2,4,5,5,6,8,9,6,4)
Levels<-c("A","","A","C",'D','D',"C","y","","")
last_entry<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
df <- data.frame(ID, day, values, Levels, last_entry)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it properly, you may want to code "empty" cells to `NA` beforehand.

```
Exampledata[Exampledata == ""] <- NA
```

Then you may use `by` from base R to look up `"day"` of the last `!is.na` entry of `"Levels"` in the by `"ID"` splitted data.

```
res <- do.call(rbind, by(Exampledata, Exampledata$ID, function(x) {
  x$last_entry <- ifelse(is.na(x$Levels), x$day[tail(which(!is.na(x$Levels)), 1)], 0)
  x
}))
```

Since the `rbind`ed result comes out ordered alphabetically by `"ID"` we can re-order it by day.

```
res <- res[order(res$day), ]
res
#         ID day values Levels last_entry
# QYZ.1  QYZ   1      1      A          0
# MMM    MMM   2      2   <NA>         NA
# QYZ.3  QYZ   3      4      A          0
# bb2    bb2   4      5      C          0
# gm6.5  gm6   5      5      D          0
# gm6.6  gm6   6      6      D          0
# YOU    YOU   7      8      C          0
# LLL.8  LLL   8      9      y          0
# LLL.9  LLL   9      6   <NA>          8
# LLL.10 LLL  10      4   <NA>          8
```

Now there are the desired last entries for the `"LLL"` level, and an `NA` for `MMM` what it logically *should* have since `"Levels"` is `NA` and it has no last entry.

#### Data

```
Exampledata <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(5L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 
3L, 3L), .Label = c("bb2", "gm6", "LLL", "MMM", "QYZ", "YOU"), class = "factor"), 
    day = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), values = c(1, 2, 
    4, 5, 5, 6, 8, 9, 6, 4), Levels = structure(c(2L, NA, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, NA, NA), .Label = c("", "A", "C", "D", 
    "y"), class = "factor"), last_entry = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: In my actual dataset, day is actually a Date (YYYY-MM-DD), any way to modify this code so it returns whatever is in the "day" column, no matter the structure of the column?